# ASP.net code does not see cookie set by browser

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, asp.net-3.5

I am using Forms Authentication in an ASP.NET 3.5 application. When I login, I can see in Chrome that the auth cookie has been set and is being sent back to the ASP.NET Development Server.

However, by the time it reaches this code in `Global.asax`:

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
```

the auth cookie set by my code is no longer present! Even though Chrome has sent the cookie for that request! Only the ASP.NET session cookie is visible in the `Context.Request`.

I've tried changing the name of the auth cookie, but that didn't help.

By the way, it is also requesting the browser to do NTLM auth even though I have changed the web.config to specify forms auth.

Comment: Could you try this - [FormsAuthentication on ASP.NET sites with the Google Chrome Browser on iOS](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx)

Comment: @Win That's not the issue - the cookie is being set, it's just not being seen by the server code.

Comment: Does your application's regular [HttpCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx) work in Chrome? Please post the code of creating **FormsAuthenticationTicket** and **authentication** tag in web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was receiving the following error in the event log:

```
 Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.
```

but I had not looked at the event log.

Apparently it is a requirement of ASP.NET to set the cookie value to an encrypted ticket, as shown in [this code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Despite what some of the documentation implies, you cannot just put anything you want in the forms authentication cookie.